# how to validate props as an array of objects?

Tags: reactjs, react-props

Here is part of a component where I pass props as an array of objects:

```
const data = [
    {
        active: true,
        status: 'Active'
    },
    {
        active: false,
        status: 'Done'
    }
]

<MyComponent myProps={data} />
```

Here is my component where I'm trying to validate props

```
import React from 'react'
import { bool, string } from 'prop-types'

const MyComponent = ({ myProps }) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Hello</h1>
        </div>
    )
}

MyComponent.propTypes = {
    active: bool.isRequired,
    status: string
}

export default MyComponent
```

The error I'm getting is:

> The prop `active` is marked as required in `MyComponent`, but its
> value is `undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are passing down as props `myProps`.`active` and `status` are part of your object shape. With that in mind your propType should look like:

```
MyComponent.propTypes = {
  myProps: PropTypes.arrayOf(
    PropTypes.shape({
      active: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
      status: PropTypes.string
    })
  )
}
```

also remember to import `PropTypes` at the top:

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
```

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'arrayOf' of undefined

Comment: updated my answer. you need also to import `PropTypes`

Comment: OK.. it works when I use PropTypes from 'prop-types' library but not from React:
import PropTypes, { bool, string } from 'prop-types'

Comment: you could destructure all instead like  `import { bool, string, arrayOf, shape } from 'prop-types'`, and remove all `PropTypes`. it's up to your preference :)

Answer (score 1):

```
MyComponent.propTypes = {
    myProps: PropTypes.arrayOf(
        PropTypes.shape({
            active: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
            status: PropTypes.string
        })
    )
    .isRequired
}
```

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'arrayOf' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

I think you need two components, a HOC (High Order Component) that receives your array, with an prop:

```
MyComponentHoc.propTypes = {
    data: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
};
```

And then Call to your visual component inside:

```
const MyComponentHoc = (data) => data.map(MyComponent);
```